# show grey lines / separator lines in an empty listView

Tags: android, xml, listview, user-interface, lines

I have a very simple listview, but now it shoes all empty when open it, I wanna user see the light grey lines in this empty list view to let them know this is something will list, Is there any way to show the lines when the listview still empty please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.anna.DiscoverActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchview"
    app:queryHint="Search HoodMark"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


<ListView
    android:layout_below="@id/searchview"
    android:id="@+id/discover_list"
    android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   </ListView>

   </RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: Isn't better to show a `ProgressDialog` while data is loaded? In this way, the user will see that something is loading

Comment: you have to create another xml file wich contain the compenent of each item listView.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is. Create an emptyView, design it as you like then supply it to the your adapter. Like this:

```
 //inflate your empty view
                    View emptyView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.emptyViewLayout,null,false);
                    //set to your listView
                    listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```